# Error importing data on production server- locally works fine

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to import this CSV file. It works perfectly on my local setup on django. However- it won't import on my actual server/production version.

I am using SQLite (locally), and Postgres on the server. But I don't see any settings that would affect it. Any suggestions?

My import file:

```
import sys, os
import django

sys.path.append('/srv/apps/stashdDB/code')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'stashdDB.settings'

django.setup()

import stashd.models as m




import csv

l = list(csv.reader(open('test_data.csv', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')))

Gender_CHOICES = {
    'Male': 1,
    'Female': 2,
    'Unisex': 3,
}

Stock_CHOICES = {
    'in stock': 1,
    'low stock': 2,
    'out of stock': 3,
    'discountinued': 4
}

for i in l[1:]:
        cat = m.Category.objects.get_or_create(category_name = i[4])[0]
        prod = m.Product(
            name = i[0],
            link = i[1],
            description = i[6],
            brand = i[7],
            gender = Gender_CHOICES[i[8]] if i[8] in Gender_CHOICES else 3,
            store = m.Store.objects.get_or_create(store_name = i[2])[0]
            )
        prod.save()
        var = m.Variation(
            product = prod,
            variation = "default"
            )
        var.save()
        img = m.Image(
            variation = var,
            image = i[5]
            )
        img.save()
        size = m.Size(
            variation = var
            )
        size.save()
        price = m.Price(
            variation = var,
            price = float(i[3])
            )
        price.save()
        stock = m.Stock(
            size = size,
            stock = Stock_CHOICES[i[9]] if i[9] in Stock_CHOICES else 4
            )
        stock.save()
        prod.category.add(cat)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update_fromcsv.py", line 18, in <module>
    l = list(csv.reader(open('test_data.csv', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')))
TypeError: 'errors' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: Have you installed Django on the server? The error is because it can't find Django package.
If you have virtualenv installed, is the virtualenv active on the server?

Comment: Check whether django is installed or virtual environment is activated in production.

Comment: Right. And also, always keep a requirements.txt in project dir. Keep on updating it whenever you update it on local after installing any package.

Comment: Yes- I have a requirements.txt which has all my pip installs/ Django is installed on the Virtualenv part of the server, and I'm running the command/import.py from the virutla env. What next can I check?

Comment: Check if it is the python in your virtual dev that is running this and not another installation of it

Comment: I dont see python come up in my "pip freeze" list- (only python-openid & python3-openid).But doesn't come up on my pip freeze list on my local version of django but it can still import using this file. Please clarify what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different versions of Python locally and on the server.

Locally, you are likely using Python 3, because [Python 3.4 knows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) the `errors` argument for `open()`

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, 
     newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)
```

On the server, you probably run Python 2, because in [in Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) the `errors` argument does not exist

```
open(name[, mode[, buffering]])
```

That's why the error message is complaining about 'errors' being "invalid".